# Developing PhoGap Application in Visual studio

Tags: asp.net, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

> Hello ! I am new to PhoneGap. I have followed the basic installation step to build the application in Windows(installing node.js,git,cordova). I can build the project as well. As a .NET developer I am very used to debugging environment where you develop your code using Visual Studio, keep break point,debug etc. This feature somewhere needed while developing PhoneGap application.

How I expect as a .NET developer while developing PhoneGap application:

> Keep breakpoint in javascript files(PhoneGap API's),
>   Debug live, make changes to index.html, css and changes reflects back to  browser/emulator.
>   Live test(not like build and then emulate)